# What is the recommended way to access microphones with nodejs?

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron, microphone

I have nodejs installed on my mashine. I have also connected microphone. Is there any way  to select and access microphone from nodejs?

I made some research on the web but web says nodejs is not a recommended way to do this, is this a relailable information?

If it cannot be done with pure nodejs, is there any way to do it with [electron](https://electron.atom.io/)?

Answer (score 1):

You can access microphone from node using this module [node-microphones](https://github.com/vincentsaluzzo/node-microphone). Also you can do that in electron, and thats depend on you application requirement and platform

Comment: How do you do it in Electron?